# What Am I? a riddle

Tags: riddle

If I am present I  may get cut out or thrown away 
Sometimes I am used to create instead of destroy
When I am unlucky I turn tang into gnat or irk into vex
I am at my worst when I arrive to the core

What am I?

Line 2:

> My process has been valued throughout the ages. Beloved by ancient kings and commoners alike!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Rot

If I am present I may get cut out or thrown away

> Rotten parts of food.

Sometimes I am used to create instead of destroy

> Wrought is a synonymy for *create*, or Rot could mean a yeast, which can be used to create bread, wine or beer (from OP  fermentation)

When I am unlucky I turn tang into gnat or irk into vex

> 13 is considered an unlucky number and rot13 does that.

I am at my worst when I arrive to the core

> Rotten to the core.

Comment: Is this better @ITAlex :)

Comment: Line 2 could refer to the homophone "wrought", which can be used as a synonym for create.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadHaberdasher, I will add that :D

Comment: Line 2 still not quite right  rot13 pbzcbfg perngrf arj guvatf. Ebg arrqf gb or gur perngbe

Comment: @TheMadHaberdasher Nice attempt but I was being a little more literal

Comment: Does it have any thing to do with creating a new word? @ITAlex

Comment: Ooh, I like this answer. Line 2 could be better explained with Ebg pbhyq zrna n lrnfg, juvpu pna or hfrq gb perngr oernq, jvar be orre

Comment: Ahh, cool I will add that @jsm :D

Comment: The exact thing I was looking for was rot13 srezragngvba but the answer is close enough for me to be satisfied +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> seed

If I am present I may get cut out or thrown away

> seeds are often cut out or thrown away

Sometimes I am used to create instead of destroy

> seeds can be used to grow new plants

When I am unlucky I turn tang into gnat or irk into vex

> A seed as in used a rotation alphabet cipher? unlucky 13 added to each letter in tang gives gnat and irk gives vex

I am at my worst when I arrive to the core

> seeds are often at the core

Comment: Interesting guess. But not quite there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a worm?

If I am present I may get cut out or thrown away

> if in an apple...

Sometimes I am used to create instead of destroy

> silk VS consuming decomposing bodies

When I am unlucky I turn tang into gnat or irk into vex

> computer worm (virus) using rot13 to alter data

I am at my worst when I arrive to the core

> a computer worm (virus) at a computer core is bad

and

> Kings like silk, commoners like butterflies